# How to reset / remove chrome's input highlighting / focus border?

Tags: css, google-chrome, focus, border

I have seen that chrome puts a thicker border on `:focus` but it kind of looks off in my case where I've used border-radius also. Is there anyway to remove that?

[image: image: chrome :focus border]

Comment: try this css, it work for me
`textarea:focus, input:focus{ border: none; }`

Answer (score 879, accepted):

You should be able to remove it using

```
outline: none;
```

but keep in mind this is potentially bad for usability: It will be hard to tell whether an element is focused, which can suck when you walk through all a form's elements using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key - you should reflect somehow when an element is focused.

Comment: i did change the `background-color` and `color` properties/attributes (whatever u call it) on `:focus` so i guess its still ok

Comment: Yep. Globally setting `outline: none` like some resets do is a mistake as it degrades keyboard accessibility, but it's fine to remove `outline` if you've got another cleart way of reflecting focusedness.

Comment: +1 on the note for this being a VERY bad practice.  It would make keyboard usage very annoying.

Comment: It's a horrible idea by Chrome, but nice they made it easy to turn off.  Of course it's bad practice if you don't do something else to show focus, but who's going to do something that silly?  It will look nice on maybe 1% of websites these days, since everyone is doing everything totally custom.  Using "standard" looking controls is a thing of the past.

Comment: But for a mobile navigation menu based on a `select` dropdown, this is very good practice.

Comment: try this css, it work for me ->
textarea:focus, input:focus{ border: none; }

Answer (score 169):

I had to do all of the following to completely remove it:

```
outline-style: none;
box-shadow: none;
border-color: transparent;
```

Example:

```css
button {
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.no-focusborder:focus {
  outline-style: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  border-color: transparent;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<p>Click in the white space, then press the "Tab" key.</p>
<button>Button 1 (unchanged)</button>
<button class="no-focusborder">Button 2 (no focus border, custom focus indicator to show focus is present but the unwanted highlight is gone)</button>
<br/><br/><br/><br/><br/><br/>
```

Comment: This should be the top answer, its the only one that completely removes the shadow/border on focus.

Comment: finally I found one that works on mobile!

Comment: Tried quite a few other things, but this is the only one that worked.

Comment: This is the one that only worked for me

Comment: This answer gets the closest, but still leaves a gray outline/shadow around the top edge of the input box.  To get rid of that I had to add a `background: white;` as well.

Comment: Thanks, worked for me!

Answer (score 84):

To remove the default focus, use the following in your default .css file :

```
:focus {outline:none;}
```

You can then control the focus border color either individually by element, or in the default .css:

```
:focus {outline:none;border:1px solid red}
```

Obviously replace `red` with your chosen hex code.

You could also leave the border untouched and control the background color (or image) to highlight the field:

```
:focus {outline:none;background-color:red}
```

:-)

Answer (score 25):

This will definitely work. Orange outline won't show up anymore..
Common for all tags:

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
   }
```

Specific to some tag, ex: input tag

```
input:focus{
   outline:none;
  }
```

Answer (score 16):

```
border:0;
outline:none;
box-shadow:none;
```

This should do the trick.

Answer (score 12):

The simpliest way is to use something like this but note that it may not be that good.

```
input {
  outline: none;
}
```

I hope you find this useful.

Answer (score 6):

you could just set `outline: none;` and border to a different color on focus.

Answer (score 5):

Problem is when you already have an outline. Chrome still changes something and it's a real pain. I cannot find what to change :

```
.search input {
  outline: .5em solid black;
  width:41%;
  background-color:white;
  border:none;
  font-size:1.4em;
  padding: 0 0.5em 0 0.5em;
  border-radius:3px;
  margin:0;
  height:2em;
}

.search input:focus, .search input:hover {
  outline: .5em solid black !important;
  box-shadow:none;
  border-color:transparent;;
 }

.search button {
  border:none;
  outline: .5em solid black;
  color:white;
  font-size:1.4em;
  padding: 0 0.9em 0 0.9em;
  border-radius: 3px;
  margin:0;
  height:2em;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#4EB4F8), to(#4198DE));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#4EB4F8, #4198DE);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #4EB4F8, #4198DE);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#4EB4F8, #4198DE);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#4EB4F8, #4198DE);
  background: linear-gradient(#4EB4F8, #4198DE);
  filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#4EB4F8', endColorstr='#4198DE');
  zoom: 1;
}
```

[image: No focus]
[image: With focus]