# Removing a focus color in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, forms

I have a colour that appears on my input and textarea fields when they are focused:

[image]

This seems to happen in Chrome, but not Firefox.

I have tried to change the color with a bit of jQuery:

```
if ($('body').is('#contact')) {
        $('input').focus(function() {
            $(this).css('border', '2px solid #ce1443');
            console.log('focus');
        });

         $('textarea').focus(function() {
            $('textarea').css('border', '2px solid #ce1443');
        });
    }
```

However, this appears to only make the current border bigger...but it does nothing to get rid of the blue colour.

Comment: May be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/chrome-inputtype-textfocus-border

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `outline: none` CSS property: http://jsfiddle.net/ZnefN/.

Comment: Hm...that seems to work in Chrome...but then I see the outline in firefox?

Comment: Wait...that's just jsfiddle adding the outline I think

Answer (score 5):

try in css:

```
input:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

and to get all input and text areas and select boxes

```
input:focus, select:focus, textarea:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Also, I think this might be redundant to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457849/how-do-i-disable-the-highlight-border-on-an-html-input-text-element)

Comment: I think setting the outline-width: 0 helped too.

Comment: Quite possibly could help in chrome, though i think IE views `outline-width` as a different kind of property and may hide borders or text-shadowing as well.  I could be wrong, I don't test with IE unless the boss makes me, but just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

It's something you can fix through CSS:

```
input:focus {
  outline: 0 none;
}
```