# Change the selection border color in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome

Whenever you press the tab key while on a web page, the browser puts a border around whatever element is selected. IE and Firefox just use a dotted gray line, but Chrome uses a solid yellow highlight. My problem is that Chrome also puts this border around any active field inputs - so whenever a Chrome user clicks one of my contact fields to input their info, that yellow border pops up around the text box and really messes up my color scheme.

Is there a way to override this behavior in chrome through CSS?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/best-way-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border

Comment: Guess I was searching with the wrong keywords

Comment: Look this theme
https://stackoverflow.com/q/3397113/9161635

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus { outline: /* whatever you want it to be */ }
```

See [here](http://beckelman.net/2008/09/15/override-chromes-automatic-border-around-active-fields-using-css/).