# Remove input focus on Google Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css

I am working with Firefox and Google Chrome.

On Firefox I have no problems and the focus color is blue.

[image: firefox focus]

On Chrome the focus is blue + orange.

[image: chrome focus]

How do I remove the orange? It comes as a default input focus in Chrome.

```css
.input {
  border: 1px solid #dbdbdb;
  padding: 0 5px 0 5px;
  height: 26px;
  width: 200px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  font-family: "Arial Black", Gadget, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.input:focus {
  border: 1px solid rgba(51, 153, 255, 0.4);
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(51, 153, 255, 0.4);
}
```

```html
<td><input type="text" name="user_login" class="input" autocomplete="off"></td>
```

Answer (score 29):

You should be able to remove it with

`outline: none`

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/cvv5h/1/

Check this out: [How to reset / remove chrome's input highlighting / focus border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/best-way-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border)

Comment: If your using bootstrap you'll also need to do box-shadow:none;

Comment: Doesn't work for me in Chrome 40.0.2214.115; I still get the blue outline