# Removing blue highlighted text on focus

Tags: html, css

When I open the modal window, the onfocus text value in the textarea is highlighted in blue color.I'm not sure what CSS properties should be used to removed the highlighted onfocus blue color from the text . I tried the below, but it ain't working.

```
input[type="text"], textarea{
    outline: none;
    box-shadow:none !important;
    border:1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

[image: Text filed value highlighted in blue]

Comment: Try this out `:focus {outline:none;}` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/best-way-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `user-select` to avoid the selection of any text

```css
input {
  -webkit-user-select: none;  /* Chrome all / Safari all */
  -moz-user-select: none;     /* Firefox all */
  -ms-user-select: none;      /* IE 10+ */
  user-select: none;          /* Likely future */      
}
```

```html
<input type="text">
```

Be careful with this, because you are avoiding to select a prompt to users, and it causes accessibility lost.

Comment: It is showing the Highlight color on chrome Version 74.0.3729.169

Answer (score 2):

An alternative to the `user-select` property [suggested by
 Marcos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33217603/128165) is to use the `::selection` and `::-moz-selection` (*on their own rules*) to specifically set/unset the color/background of the selected text (*without disabling the select functionality*).

```css
input[type="text"]::selection,
textarea::selection {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: red;
}
input[type="text"]::-moz-selection,
textarea::-moz-selection {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: red;
}

input[type="text"],
textarea {
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" value="test value for selection" />
<hr/>
<textarea>test text for selection</textarea>
```