# How to add border to focus css

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to add styling input text box that has a red border when clicked and no border when you click away. 
I have tried styling `input:active` but the problem is that when you click away, the red border is still there. Rather than `input:active` I wan't to manipulate the `input:focus` to have a red border like so

```
 textarea:focus, input:focus{
        outline: none; 
        border: 1px solid red;
  }
```

is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> is there a way to do this?

Yes, just do it. Your suggested CSS rules are the right choice as evidenced by the following snippet:

```css
textarea:focus, input:focus {
  outline: none; 
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<input type="text">
```

See also [How to reset / remove chrome's input highlighting / focus border?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/how-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border)

Comment: I see. I thought styling focus was an issue but I think I had some conflicting classes in there that prevented it from working the first time.

Comment: If you think, this had solved your problem, you should mark this answer as accepted (click on the gray check box, below the downvote button)