# Scss - disable border on click

Tags: css, sass

I'm creating carousel with ngb-Bootstrap and i have problem with border. When i click on carousel buttons or everywhere in carousel i have sth like this:

[image]

I don't want to display this border outside. I was trying to remove border on active or on focus but nothing works.

```
.imageCarousel {
        max-height: 500px;
        text-align: center;
        color: $color2;

        user-select: none;


        img {
            max-width: 80%;
            max-height: 280px;

        }
        .carousel-indicators {
            color: $color2;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try adding `outline: none;` to the buttons. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943548/how-to-reset-remove-chromes-input-highlighting-focus-border)

Comment: `outline: none`

Comment: Don't use an element which is focusable if you don't want a focus state. This is assuming you don't want users to be able to interact with your slider at all…

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Or you can be more specific with a CSS class (like `.imageCarousel`).

Comment: Bad advice. Disabling outlines on elements that should have an outline is big f**k-you to your users. Accessibility, it's a thing. Why not use an element that doesn't have a focus state?

Comment: @SethWarburton To show nothing on focus, that's a bad idea, that's true. (If the developer writes custom CSS for `:focus`, it's okay.) But this was the answer for the question.

Comment: Your use of the universal selector destroys focus states on every element; bringing a gun to a knife fight. Yes, it did solve the OP's problem but not in a particularly responsible way.